# What are these 'code' columns in this csv and what does Pandas pivot method do with it?

Tags: dataset, pandas, data, csv

In a csv discussed in the book HoML (hands on machine learning), what do the values in capital letters represent? Are these some sort of code? Also, it seems the pandas.pivot() methods does something with these values. So what are these values for and what does pandas.pivot() do with it?

```
oecd_bli = pd.read_csv(datapath + "oecd_bli_2015.csv", thousands=',')
oecd_bli = oecd_bli[oecd_bli["INEQUALITY"]=="TOT"]
oecd_bli = oecd_bli.pivot(index="Country", columns="Indicator", values="Value")
```

The csv is available in this link of the homl github.

[link to csv on homl github](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/datasets/lifesat/oecd_bli_2015.csv)

I looked at other .csv and they look different, also I searched on the pandas help but didn't get the answer.

thank you

Comment: please consult the data source.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you provided, the `README.md` does provide the original data source: https://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?DataSetCode=BLI#

There you can see that the values mean: "Total", "Men", "Women", "High" and "Low"

The `pivot()` method in `pandas` is used to reshape data. In your code snippet, it transforms the data so that each row represents a country, each column represents a different indicator, and cell values are the corresponding values from the original dataset.